# Error email with the process TemplateNotificationGenerator with activity

Tags: acumatica

I dont' understand why I have this error *"Create message failed. Email recipient should be defined"*, but I have the recipient with the to

```
    Notification notification = PXSelect<Notification,Where<Notification.notificationID, Equal<Required<Notification.notificationID>>>>.Select(pg, 904077);
    if (notification==null) {PXTrace.WriteInformation("notification vide"); }       
    
    bool sent = false;
    string sError = "Failed to send E-mail.";
    try
    {
      TemplateNotificationGenerator sender = 
TemplateNotificationGenerator.Create(une_attestation, notification.NotificationID.Value);
     sender.MailAccountId = (notification.NFrom.HasValue) ? notification.NFrom.Value : PX.Data.EP.MailAccountManager.DefaultMailAccountID; 
    
     sender.To = "xxxxxx@gmail.com";  
     sent |= sender.Send().Any();
```